# MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; while creating function with simple if else

Tags: mysql, function

I have written an simple function with if else statement 
it is giving an error

MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 25

I tried to find out but can one please help me on it

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `age_group`(`user_id` INT, `match_id` INT) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET latin1
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
declare userdob,matchdob date;
declare userage,matchage int;

select users.dob into userdob from users where users.id = user_id;
select users.dob into matchdob from users where users.id = match_id;

SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, userdob, CURDATE()) into userage ;

SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, matchdob, CURDATE()) into matchage ;

IF(userage >= 16 and matchage >= 16) THEN
 RETURN 'opens';
else if(userage >= 8 and matchage >= 8 and userage < 12 and matchage < 12 ) then  
RETURN '8-12';
else if(userage >= 12 and matchage >= 12 and userage < 14 and matchage < 14 ) then  
RETURN '12-14';
else if(userage >= 14 and matchage >= 14 and userage < 16 and matchage < 16 ) then  
RETURN '14 - 16';       
else
return NULL;
end if;   
END
```

Comment: Post the complete function code. May be the issue with delimiter.

Comment: Where do the user_id and match_id fields come from? Are they passed to the procedure?

Comment: those two were function parameters passed as    SET @p0 = '1';

SET @p1 = '2';

SELECT `age_group` (
@p0 , @p1
) AS `age_group` ;